# NHibernate QueryOver NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have following QueryOver which throws NullReferenceException when newExam.ActiveTo is null (ActiveTo type is DateTime?)

```
Exam examAlias = null;
examsInSameTime = session.QueryOver(() => examAlias)
                            .Where(() => examAlias.ActiveTo == null && newExam.ActiveTo == null)
                            .Future<Exam>();
```

When I rewrote query to this HQL everything works fine

```
var query = "from Exam exam where exam.ActiveTo is null and :newExamActiveTo is null)";
examsInSameTime = session.CreateQuery(query)                
            .SetParameter("newExamActiveTo", newExam.ActiveTo).List<Exam>();
```

Why QueryOver throws exception and HQL not?

Comment: But, your queries are not the same, right? The QueryOver checks some (mostlikely) local param newExam... while HQL creates SQL param, which is passed and check on DB side.. which is redundant. Maybe you should rethink your query at all...

Comment: But even that queries are not exactly same, why QueryOver throws that exception? What is wrong with newExaim.ActiveTo == null ? I have multiple selecting criteria which I want use in query depending on some local param newExam values are null or not

Comment: I guess I understand what you are trying to do... so I tried to express that in my answer... it should show you how we can split "params" evaluation... It is just HOW TO...not exact solution. But honestly, exactly this way I do solve querying ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that solution here should be surprisingly simple and elegant *(but only if I do read your issue correctly)*.

The point is - check your params in C#, do not send that into DB side:

```
Exam examAlias = null;
var query = session.QueryOver(() => examAlias);

//here we will check what needed
if(newExam.ActiveTo == null)
{
    query.Where(() => examAlias.ActiveTo == null)
}

// we can repeat that many times and build WHERE clause as required
...

// finally the query
examsInSameTime = query.Future<Exam>();
```

So, the trick here is:

- check the search params on application side
- if needed, convert them into SQL WHERE statement
- send on DB side only restrictions which are required

Comment: Thanks, you are correct! I ended up with this solution. I am still curious why original query in my question throws exception, but dynamically making query as in your answer seems much better and more elegant as you stated.

Comment: Great to see that, sir :) Enjoy mighty NHibernate :)

Answer (score 0):

As written by Radim, you are using a parameter inside the `QueryOver`. The problem is that `newExam` is probably `null` when you execute the query.

Comment: Yes, the newExam is parameter inside QueryOver but it is definetely not null. Just newExam.ActiveTo is null. When I set newExam.ActiveTo = DateTime.UtcNow before running query, query return result with no problems

Comment: @Minarja Try putting it in a temp variable... `DateTime? dt = newExam.ActiveTo` and use `dt` in the query

Comment: I'm sorry, `newExam.ActiveTo` type is already `DateTime?`, there was typo in my question. Also I tried it put to temporal `dt` variable but still the result is just that exception.

Comment: @Minarja You are doing a `Future`, so you don't consume the data immediately. Can you try a `List()`?